# Prismajs, добавлять одинаковые записи в базу данных

Tags: mysql, typescript, prisma

У меня есть 2 модели

```
model Post {
  id          Int          @id @default(autoincrement())
  title       String?
  text        String?
  countLikes  Boolean      @default(false)
  countComent Boolean      @default(false)
  countWatch  Int          @default(0)
  imgAvatar   String?
  user        User         @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId      Int
  delete      Boolean      @default(false)
  likes       LikePost[]
  coment      ComentPost[]
}

model ComentPost {
  id     Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  user   User   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId Int
  post   Post   @relation(fields: [postId], references: [id])
  postId Int
  text   String?
  delete Boolean @default(false)
}
```

С помощью запроса,я создаю коментарий с userId и postId

```
  async setcoment(userId, postId, text) {
    let newComent = await this.prisma.comentPost.create({
      data: {
          userId:userId,
          postId:postId,
          text:text
      },
    });
    return newComent
  }
```

Запись добавляется,все отличное. но если я опять захочу добавить коментарий, то  уже не получится, выдает ошибку

```
let newComent = await this.prisma.comentPost.create(
Unique constraint failed on the constraint: `ComentPost_userId_key`
```

Хотелось бы иметь записи если userId или postId уже есть.

Comment: может быть вам стоит сгенерировать и запустить миграцию?

Comment: Пробовал, не помогло

Comment: Если верить ошибке **Unique constraint failed** то у вас на поле стоит проверка уникальности значения. Скорее всего индекс с именем **ComentPost_userId_key**. Измените индекс и уберите уникальность с поля.

Comment: я сделал скрипт с вашей структурой и с созданием 2х комментариев и у меня нет вашей ошибки https://pastebin.com/nWUycQmb

Comment: @nörbörnën а они точно создаются? Потому что у меня только 1 создается)

Comment: 2 записи в таблице, я проверил

Comment: Очень странно..